# iOS autofill assumes the field before password is the username

Tags: ios, ios11, autofill

The autofill works incredibly well, but I have one scenario when it isn't optimal and I am not aware of a work around a perhaps a proper way of doing it.

I have a screen with 2 UITextFields, first one is Amount, a monetary value to be transferred to another person. The second field is the password, the user will need to re-enter his password before the transaction can be completed.

The first field (Amount) has content type set as .unspecified and the second field (password) has it set to .password

When the user taps the second field Autofill beautifully suggest the the password to be used, but once the correct password is tapped, iOS automatically assumes the first field (amount) is the username and fills it with the username associated with the selected account, overwriting the amount the user had previously entered.

Is there a way to force password only autofill?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the field to something other than "unspecified"; e.g.name, or perhaps creating a hidden text field with the type set to username?

Comment: Set it to `UITextContentType("unspecified")` OR `.oneTimeCode` lol

Comment: I did, regardless of what I set it to, it still gets the username assigned to it.
Hidden text field set to username would be a solution, although a bit hacky for my liking.

Speaking of a hacky solution, what I am doing at the moment is using the UITextFieldDelegate with textFieldDidEndEditing. At the first time if the field is a double, I store it in memory, at the second time, after it gets the username, if the field is not double, I assigned the value stored in memory.

I will compile an answer with all these methods, but I will wait a bit until perhaps someone has the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Today i face the same issue, with some different way. My situation is taking input of `mobile number` and `password` entry into the login page. Native app only support for mobile number while the web app support for `email` only. So while iOS autofill is in action, it fill the mobile number field with the `email` field, which is not acceptable.

After playing sometime with the autofill, i have found the life-cycle of the `UITextField` delegate is somewhat different in case of autofill.

When a autofill is tapped which is provided in the top of the keyboard, the `UITextFieldDelegate` start working from the beginning. **Although the keyboard is open the delegate method started from the current with call order as follows**

1. `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`
2. `textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)`

This delegate calls without the keyboard dismissing and re-appear again. This is unusual. **Returning `false` in the `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` has no effect in this case.**

So theoretically i have the chance to edit the `mobile field` in the `textFieldShouldEndEditing`. To do that i keep track of the text which was present before the autofill begin. so took two variable as follows

```
var previousText: String?
var nextText: String?
```

Whenever a `UITextField` begin editing, i save it in `previousText` as following

```
public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    previousText = textField.text
}
```

then i track the changes inside the `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` as following

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    nextText = self.getCompleteString(original: textField.text, replacingRange: range, withString: string)


    // YOU MAY RETURN `true` OR `false` BASED ON KEYBOARD TYPING, BUT RETURNING `false` IN CASE OF AUTOFILL HAS NO EFFECT. SO I ASSUME, YOU RETURN `true` ALWAYS.
    return true;
}

func getCompleteString(original: String?, replacingRange: NSRange, withString: String) -> String? {
    guard var originalText = original else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let range = Range<String.Index>.init(replacingRange, in: originalText) else {
        return nil
    }

    originalText.replaceSubrange(range, with: withString)

    return originalText
}
```

Now the most interesting part, detecting custom requirement (in my case detecting a possible valid mobile number, where your case was detecting a valid amount)

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == MY_MOBILE_TEXT_FIELD {
       if nextText.IS_POSSIBLE_VALID_MOBILE_NUMBER() { // my function to detect the possible valid mobile number
           textField.text = nextText
       } else {
           textField.text = previousText
       }
    }
}
```

It worked for me, hope it works for you too.

Comment: You can try using textContentType to textfield so iOS does not messes up your input constraints on text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Autofill disregards what textfield delegate methods return

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

So can try another hack which worked for me,
You can set textContentType of amount text field to password type and use a toolbar on the keyboard to side autofill suggestions(Since you would be using num pad for entering digits in the amount field so you might already be using a custom toolbar).

```
amount_text_field.textContentType = .password
```

This way, iOS will assume it to be a password textfield and would not fill usernames or passwords which were applied from other textfields. And using toolbar should help you hide autofill suggestions on this textfield.